# Comparar dados de uma tabela no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Bom dia.

Eu tenho duas tabelas na mesma base de dados, com o mesmo nome, porém em esquemas diferentes. Eu quero comparar os registros que tem nelas, pra saber se existem dados idênticos. Tem algum software que faz isso?

Comment: Pode fazer isso via consulta mesmo, só precisa definir o que/quais são dados idênticos.

Answer (score 1):

Se a comparação for de todas as colunas:

```
SELECT sc.*, gc.*
  FROM geral.cargo gc
 INNER JOIN serv.cargo sc 
    ON gc.* <> sc.* 
   AND gc.id=sc.id;
```

> A cláusula `ON` aceita diversas comparações.